# How can I make a spectogram out of a wav file

Tags: matlab

Well I want to make a spectogram of a song. The first 10 seconds are the points of my interest. 
Should I just do this or is it wrong if I am wrong correct me.

Commands:

```
song = wavread('C:\Path of My FIle\song.wav')

length(song)/44100

song_seg = lovers(44100*1 : 44100*10)

plot(song_seg) % this command makes my spectogram Hz/Time
```

Comment: A wave file stores the wave samples, not the frequencies; you have to do an FFT to get a frequency spectrogram.

Comment: See this: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html

Answer (score 4):

First of all, where did lovers come from, and what is the significance of the number 44100? The easiest way to create a spectrogram is to use the spectrogram function of Matlab. The following code will generate a spectrogram for a specified wave file--you can experiment with the window size and window overlap parameters to find a plot which suits your needs the best.

```
[song, fs] = wavread('C:\Path of My File\song.wav');
song = song(1:fs*10);
spectrogram(song, windowSize, windowOverlap, freqRange, fs, 'yaxis');

%Larger Window Size value increases frequency resolution
%Smaller Window Size value increases time resolution
%Specify a Frequency Range to be calculated for using the Goertzel function
%Specify which axis to put frequency

%%EXAMPLE
spectrogram(song, 256, [], [], fs, 'yaxis');
%Window Size = 256, Window Overlap = Default, Frequency Range = Default
%Feel free to experiment with these values
```

Comment: but i gives an error cant find windowSize windowoverlap and freqRange

Comment: windowSize, windowOverlap, and freqRange are all parameters that you can specify. I edited in an example of one possible set of parameters

Comment: I also edited in the lines to select the first 10 seconds--hope this helps!

Comment: can you tell me how can i specify and find all these have no idea thanks

Comment: 44100 is the sample rate of PCM-encoded data from a CD, in `Hz`.

Comment: would you mind giving me an example of how its done thanks again

Comment: substitute values in the spectrogram function: spectrogram(song, WindowSize goes here, WindowOverlap goes here, Specific range of frequencies to be calculated goes here, fs, 'yaxis');

Comment: Mathworks documentation has some examples and explanations as Luis Mendo pointed out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html

A blank parameter, [], indicates that the default will be used